# What does enctype="utf8" mean in HTML form?

Tags: html, forms, enctype

According to e.g. [What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) there are 3 possible arguments for the `enctype` attribute in an HTML form:

- `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` (the default)
- `"multipart/form-data"`
- `"text/plain"`

But I have also seen `enctype="utf8"` in some forms. Is it common to use this too, and how does it relate to the 3 possibilities above?

Comment: It's not a valid option, so the invalid value default (`"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`) is used instead.

Comment: You mean `enctype="multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8"`

Comment: The first comment on the linked story is a link to the part of the spec https://www.w3.org/html/wg/spec/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fs-enctype about valid values for `enctype`. Not sure what else is needed.

Comment: I have seen it exactly like `enctype="utf8"`. If this is not valid, then it's ok.